# Rudin's definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, real-numbers

Walter Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis defines the derivative as follows in Definition 5.1:

> Let $f$ be defined (and real-valued) on $[a,b]$. For any $x \in [a,b]$ form the quotient
>   $$\phi(t) = \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\qquad(a<t<b, t \neq x)$$
>   and define
>   $$f'(x) = \lim_{t\to x}\phi(t),$$
>   provided this limit exists (we use the epsilon-delta definition here). We thus associate with the function $f$ a function $f'$ whose domain is the set of points $x$ at which the limit exists; $f'$ is called the derivative of $f$. If $f'$ is defined at a point $x$, $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

I have a doubt about this definition, and really hope someone can help me out!

1. If $[a,b]$ is the domain of $f$, how is differentiability for arbitrary functions with holes defined? For $f$ to be differentiable at $x$, can we just take any closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $x \in [a,b]$, and if the above limit exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$?
2. Clearly, the answer to the previous question must be no. For otherwise, for some $x$, I can always take the interval $[x,x]$ and the limit won't be defined there. Or, I can also take the interval $[x,x+5]$ where the limit might exist, but the limit might not exist in $[x-5,x+5]$.
3. Thus, can we define $f$ to be differentiable at $x$ if and only if either

   - there exists $[a,b]$ such that $a < x < b$ and Rudin's definition above holds for this $[a,b]$
   - or there does not exist such $[a,b]$, so $x$ is an endpoint in the domain of $f$, and Rudin's definition holds for some $[a,b]$ for which $x \in [a,b]$.

   I think the derivative is uniquely defined for each $x$ in such a definition. However this seems to be a very convoluted definition, and I don't see it anywhere.

As an example, consider the function $f:[1,2]\cup[3,4]\to\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x)=x$. Is the function differentiable at $x=3$?

Comment: What are "functions with holes"?

Comment: Maybe she means "jumps". I guess the first point is to do with showing continuity is a consequence of differentiability.

Comment: The definition applies to any $x$ in the closed interval $[a,b]$ on which $f$ is defined. It is clear. Now it may be that the notion of differentiability can be extended beyond the case covered in this definition - but to apply this definition you need a function defined on a closed interval.

Comment: @MarkBennet Is there a standard notion of differentiability for functions $f$ with arbitrary domains $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the limit function only exists if $a < b$. Next, you are right with the second example of 2. Derivatives at boundary points are a little bit tricky but if the function is not defined outside of $[a,b]$ then you don't run into any problems. The example you mention at last is correct, $f$ is differentiable at $x=3$.

What you may have misunderstood: You first fix the domain of $f$ and then define the derivative on a subset of that domain. This way you may get different derivatives for different domains of the same function. For exampele $f(x) = \vert x \vert$ is differentiable in $x=0$ if you choose either $[0,1]$ or $[-1,0]$ as the domain of $f$ but the derivatives do not coincide.

Comment: excellent example for differentiability's domain dependence +1

Comment: It's a little bit pedantic though. You normally don't run into this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and the great example! But if differentiability is domain dependent then why is it always the case that the domain is not explicitly stated? For example, the book mentions that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x\in[a,b]$ and $g(x)\neq 0$, then the quotient $f/g$ is differentiable at $x$ too. $f/g$ might no longer be defined for the whole interval $[a,b]$, so what would be the correct interval here?

Comment: That's precisely why a function is not defined only by a formula, but also by its domain and codomain. The functions $\lvert x\rvert$ on $[0,1]$ and on [-1,0]$ are different functions.

Comment: @Wakaka In this example the derivative is not domain dependent. To be formally correct you would have to choose a domain for $\frac f g$ but for any intervall $[a,b]$ such that $a\leq x\leq b$ and $g(y)\neq 0 \, \forall y \in [a,b]$ the derivatives of $\frac f g$ coincide in $x$. This is why you informally just say $\frac f g$ is differentiable in $x$.

Comment: @Zardo Wow this makes a lot of sense! In that case, let me clarify: I suppose we can informally say $f$ is differentiable at $x$ without stating an interval domain if, 1. $f$ is defined on some interval $[a,b], a<b$ that contains $x$, and 2. for all $[a,b]$ where $a<b, x\in[a,b]$, the derivative exists. I think we can prove that this derivative, if exists, is unique across all intervals. Does this definition seem sound?

Comment: @Wakaka Unfortunatly, I already gave a counterexample above! But you can definitly do so if you further demand $a<x<b$ which some people actually do.

Comment: @Zardo In your example I can take for example $[-1,1]$ and the derivative would not exist. So $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. I think we can prove the unique derivative like this: if $f$ has different derivatives at $x$ in some two intervals $[a,x]$ and $[x,b]$ for which $f$ is defined on then there won't be a derivative in $[a,b]$, contradiction. I guess I could demand $a < x < b$ but this wouldn't handle differentiability at endpoints (so we can only say $f$ is differentiable on $E$ if $E$ is open)

Comment: I misunderstood your intention. What you're basically using is differentiability from the left/right. As usual with real valued limits, if they coincide, the function is differentiable!

Comment: @Zardo Alright! I think this definition is way simpler and more intuitive than I imagined. Thanks so much for your help!